# How multi match and type phrase is used on _all

Tags: elasticsearch

Let 's say I have the following code:

```
 "multi_match": {
                                        "query": x,
                                         "type": "phrase",
                                         "fields":"_all",   
                                     }
```

x is a keyword in an array of keywords and I want to search for exact keyword. I know that using _all will concatenate the values for each filed into one big string separated by tabs. Now, my question is that in the above example x is searched in each indexed value?

Thanks,

Comment: Since that's the only filter (the multi_match) then it will search all fields in the index/type.

Comment: Thanks @ShaunMolloy so, what you mean is that if the keyword is heart, heart will be search in the value of each field that has been indexed? for example, if _all includes 100 fields, it will be searched 100 times, for each value that has been indexed for each field?

Comment: The drawback to it is the results are not really retrieved, so you don't get the field:value return you would normally get. It depends on what you want to do with the response. You might be better preparing the fields and then parsing the data.

Comment: Thanks @ShaunMolloy. Just another question and I am sorry if it seems a simple question. When I search for something all I see is the number of hits and other stuff that are in json format, these returned json results are the same if I use multi-match with specific fields, or with _all fields.  So, why does it matter?

Comment: Passing specific fields will only impose a limit for that part of the query. Since you pass all it's not restricted and will search throughout. Though there are a number of ways to do the queries to do the same thing.